# What do you call a graph where you color a grid based on some measure?

Tags: data-visualization

I mean something like [this chart](https://github.com/glennblock) showing the frequencies of a user's public contributions on GitHub.

[image]

I really like this kind of chart, as I think that they display the intended data in a really nice and easy to see way, but I have no clue what they are called, so I can't look for a library to help me generate them.
Can someone tell me the name of this type of graph / chart?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are looking at a [heat map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_map). The one you link to is a fancy interactive version that presumably requires java code.  In `R` the function would be [?heatmap](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/heatmap.html).  There is a tutorial for how to make them in `R` [here](http://flowingdata.com/2010/01/21/how-to-make-a-heatmap-a-quick-and-easy-solution/).  This is the initial output of their code:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That's it. I guess I didn't think of it as a heat map because mentally I associated HeatMaps to spacial graphs, kind lof like this one: http://www.clicktale.com/sites/default/files/field/image/mouse-move-heatmap.png , but I guess this next one is a good example of how they actually overlap http://www.zerohedge.com/sites/default/files/images/user5/imageroot/2013/07/PMI%20heatmap_0.jpg . Thanks!

Comment: Now knowing the name of the graph I was looking for, it looks its a sub-specialty of the Heatmaps called (quite aptly) "Calendar Heat Map".

If somebody (like me) is looking for an example in Javascript, checkout http://kamisama.github.io/cal-heatmap/